# "the CodeResources file must be a symbolic link to _CodeSignature..." when submit to App Store

Tags: xcode, build

Today I build my First App and submit my App to App Store. and got the following error message :

> this bundle is invalid.The CodeResources file must be a symbolic link to _CodeSignature/CodeResources. Make certain that the bundle is on a locally-mounted volume[not a remote SMB volum], and be certain to use the Mac OS X finder to compress it

I create the IPA file using `xcodebuild`, such as:

`xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath MyApp.xcarchive -exportPath ~/Desktop/MyApp.ipa -exportProvisioningProfile $provisioningName`

I don't know the relationship between `symbolic` and `CodeResources` , and what `using Finder to compress` means? compress IPA file to zip file ?

How could I fix that error? I hope someone can help me . thanks very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally , I Fixed it. the following is my solution:

```
//unzip your ipa file to AppContainer folder 
unzip YourApp.ipa -d AppContainer/

//change directory in your App folder
cd AppContainer/Payload/YourApp.app

//create a symbolic link with `ln`
ln -s _CodeSignature/CodeResources CodeResources

//and then ,zip Payload folder to YourApp
zip -y -r YourFinalApp.ipa Payload/
```

However I Fixed it ,but I do not know why should I have to do this step .

Comment: Thanks man you save my day , just add rm CodeResources before create new one ( ln -s _CodeSignature/CodeResources CodeResources )